# How to access which voice channel user writing command is in discord.py?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I'm beginning to make a discord music bot with discord.py. I've learned how to connect a bot to a voice channel when a user writes the command: dj/play. However, I'd like the bot to join the voice channel the user writing the command is in. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
 #imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint
import aiohttp
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import os

# dotenv.load_dotenv()

#setup
audio_downloder = YoutubeDL({'format':'bestaudio'})
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("dj/"))

#commands
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def flip(self, ctx):
        num = randint(0,2)
        if num == 0:
            await ctx.send("It's heads")
        elif num == 1:
            await ctx.send("No")
        else:
            await ctx.send("It's tails")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="Dev Train")
        voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        await voice_channel.connect()


async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print(f"{message.guild} - {message.channel} - {message.author} <{message.author.id}>: {message.content}")



client.add_listener(on_message)

client.add_cog(MyCog(client))
client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Thanks to the person who removed the token from my post! I'm new to this and completely forgot that you shouldn't post that online

Comment: No worries, I'd suggest you to re-generate your token as you can still see the token in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66080595/revisions) tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
# join command
@commands.command(description="joins a voice channel")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
            return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            vc = ctx.voice_client

# leave command
@commands.command(description="stops and disconnects the bot from voice")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if it works for you!

Comment: What is the command do disconnect the bot?

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the leave command.

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing called `Converters` (you can read more about them [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#converters)). You can take use of the special `VoiceChannelConverter`, it works by simply typehinting the argument in the command

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, voice_channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    print(type(voice_channel)) # -> discord.channel.VoiceChannel
    await voice_channel.connect()
```

To invoke

```
{prefix}play #channel        | channel mention
{prefix}play 716389123897123 | channel ID
{prefix}play general         | channel name
```

To get the current users voice channel

```py
@command.command()
async def play(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        return await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await voice_channel.connect()
```

Comment: Alright, make sure to accept the answer if it helped